# Why never called ommouseenter event in TWebBrowser (IE9 is Installed)

Tags: delphi, internet-explorer-9, twebbrowser

I want to handle ommouseenter event, but event never called from TWebBrowser. Although I successfully catch onmousemove event. Current Browser IE9. My code:

```
var
  D3: IHTMLDocument3;
begin

  if Supports(WebBrowser1.Document, IHTMLDocument3, D3) then
  begin
    eo1 := TEventObject.Create(self.EventHadler);
    D3.attachEvent('onmouseenter', eo1);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you try the same thing using TEmbeddedWB from www.bsalsa.com? I have found many things work better in TEmbeddedWB, than TWebBrowser, although the internal functionality of IE remains the same, the EmbeddedWB wrapper is loads more functional. It might already provide a Delphi event for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to attach the event handler to every element of interest. If you are interested in all elements then you have to loop through all elements:

```
var
  All: IHTMLElementCollection;
  Element2: IHTMLElement2;
  i: Integer;
begin
  Handler:= TEventObject.Create(Self.EventHandler);
  All:=(WebBrowser1.ControlInterface.Document as IHTMLDocument2).All;
  for i:=0 to All.Length-1 do
  begin
    Element2:=All.item(i,EmptyParam) as IHTMLElement2;
    Element2.AttachEvent('onmouseenter', Handler);
  end;
end;
```

So in an ideal world you would attach the handler after receiving `DocumentComplete` for the document of interest and detach again in `BeforeNavigate`.

There can be several problems though you should be aware of:

- the document may never finish loading (this is often caused by frames containing advertisements when some ad server doesn't serve, so the frame prevents the main document from firing the `DocumentComplete`) thus your event handlers would never be attached
- scripts might modify the page and add elements which then wouldn't have the event handler attached
- you manually have to go into `FRAMEs`/ `IFRAMEs` and attach the handlers there

I also wish it would be as easy as your approach. This would save us a lot of this hassle.

Answer (score 4):

I quess that the reason is that [ommouseenter event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not bubble. IOW it only fires when the mouse pointer moves over the element you attached the event to. So you can't use one "generic" eventhandler, you have to attach to each and every element youre instred in.

Answer (score 1):

As **ain** has pointed out, `onmouseenter` does not bubble, but as [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536945%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says,

> Unlike the onmouseover event, the onmouseenter event does not bubble. In other words, the onmouseenter event does not fire when the user moves the mouse pointer over elements contained by the object, whereas onmouseover does fire.

So you can use [onmouseover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536949%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The event occurs when the user moves the mouse pointer into the object, and it does not repeat unless the user moves the mouse pointer out of the object and then back into it.

```
procedure MyEvent;
var
  Doc: OleVariant;
begin
  Doc := Form1.WebBrowser1.Document;
  Form1.Label1.Caption := Doc.parentWindow.event.srcElement.outerHTML;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  D3: IHTMLDocument3;
begin
  if Supports(WebBrowser1.Document, IHTMLDocument3, D3) then
    D3.attachEvent('onmouseover', TEventObject.Create(MyEvent) as IDispatch);
end;
```